# How to paste [array count] to case:

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, switch-statement

I have switch. One of the cases must be a count of array:

```
    int count = [array count];
    switch (someValue) {
        case 0:
            [self foo];
            break;
        case count:
            [self bar];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

But compiler tolds:

```
Expression is not an integer constant expression
```

How to make const int from [array count]?

Comment: Not possible. Switch doesn't work that way, you'd have to create your own switch-esque control structure (which I can do, if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, the cases must all be constants. You'll need an `if` statement to check the dynamic case:

```
    int count = [array count];
    switch (someValue) {
        case 0:
            [self foo];
            break;
        default:
            if (someValue == count)
                [self bar];
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(some value == 0) {
    [self foo];
} else if (someValue == [array count]) {
    [self bar]
}
```